# Unable to style 'ul > li' elements using : document.getElementById() / ClassName() / TagName() / etc

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname, getelementsbytagname

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    let nav = document.getElementById('navbar').style;
    let navImg = document.getElementById('navBrand').style;

    nav.height = '6vh';
    nav.backgroundColor = '#00570e';
    nav.fontSize = '1vh';

    navImg.width = '4vh';
    navImg.height = '4vh';

  } else if (e.deltaY < 0) {

    document.getElementById('navbar').style = '';
    document.getElementById('navBrand').style = '';

  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "DeltaY value : " + e.deltaY;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  margin-top: 15vh;
}

#navbar {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: green;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px #00000050;
}

#navbar>img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 1vh;
  left: 3vw;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 3vw;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 1rem;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onwheel="myFunction(event)">

  <div id="navbar">
    <img id="navBrand" src="https://rb.gy/0sjhmw">
    <ul>
      <li>Bottom</li>
      <li>Top</li>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <h1>Some Heading</h1>

  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>

  <br>
  <p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to shrink/expand the Navbar and its elements depending upon the scroll direction (using `e.deltaY`).

All works well except the `ul > li` elements. They simply doesn't want to change their `fontSize` or `color` or any other styling attributes.

I have tried everything as mentioned in the title ;

```
document.getElementById()
document.getElementsByClassName()
document.getElementsByTagName()
//etc.
```

### While scrolling up:

[image]

### While scrolling down:

[image]

This is the maximum target I've achieved, but it would be better if I were able to **shrink** & **expand** the `fontSize` or alter **styling** of the text as well!

Comment: Please be specific; what are you passing to `document.getElementById(), document.getElementsByClassName(), document.getElementsByTagName()` in attempt to access the `<li>` elements? These elements don't have ids or classes, so those selectors wouldn't be relevant.

Comment: Used all of them with proper .classes and #id, but it just didn't wanted to change...
The First Child; 'ul > li' worked when I gave it an #id instead of a .class but obviously I am not willing to give each and every 'li' tag a different #id and alter everyone in JS later.... That's just dumb code

Comment: Here's my suspicion: `element.style` doesn't save a reference to the object, just the style. So when you try to set `nav.height`, it's only updating the saved style object ,not the original element. Try using, for example, `nav = document.getElementById('navbar')`, then later `nav.style.height = 6vh`.

Comment: Initially tried that too... didn't work.
But the `classList.add()` looks useful and easy, will be going with that
:)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try `document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(...)` ?

Comment: Yes tried that too, didn't worked well, but the classList method looks useful :)